# Twitter Boostrap 3 page is not responsive

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I created a sample page with a header containing an image. But the page is not responsive. I added the class `img-responsive` to the `img` tag but yet it is not responsive. Here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html>
    <head>
        <title>A Sample Bootstrap Page</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
        <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
        <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>
        <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
     </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="page-header" id="header">
                <img id="logo" src="img/logo.png" height="100" alt="Image" class="img-responsive">
                <p>Some text here</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

The style.css includes the following:

```
#header #logo
{
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
```

Comment: You are hardcoding the height of the img with height="100", remove that to start with.

Comment: And does `style.css` contain any styles for `.page-header`?

Comment: @Last1Here style.css contains only #header #logo defintion

Comment: It doesnt work. Even the contents of the p tag are not responsive. And the image has become larger and not responsive.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the img tag height="100" as suggested above and add this to your style.css

```
#header #logo {
   display: block;
   margin-left: auto;
   margin-right: auto;
   height: 100px;
}
```

As for the image not being responsive make sure the bootstrap style for .img-responsive is being used

In firebug/developer tools you should see a class of

```
.img responsive {
   max-width: 100%;
   height: auto;
   display: block;
}
```

As for resolving your issue I'll be glad to solve it if you can make a codepen/snippet example for me to see/look at

Answer (score 0):

You should do like this,even needn't use custom class to style, bootstrap provided enough.

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-12">
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/1900/100/" alt="" class="img-responsive">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-12">
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/1900/100/" alt="" class="img-responsive">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I'd just recommend using the "container" class as Java Enthusiast did as "container-fluid" class has width: 100% unlike "container".

Comment: Could you clarify your answer with how this approach is different and why it's better? Code-only answers without comments are rarely useful.